# Is there a neat way to invert this semi-sparse $6\times6$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Can anyone see a neat way to invert this matrix?

$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc} 
a  & b & 0  & c  & 0 & 0  \\
2d & e & 2b & 0  & f & 0  \\
0  & d & g  & 0  & 0 & h  \\
A  & 0 & 0  & B  & b & 0  \\
0  & C & 0  & 2D & E & 2b \\
0  & 0 & F  & 0  & D & G  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Entries are elements of $\mathbb{R}$. It's several years since I have studied linear algebra, need to remind myself of the techniques. Due to the number of zeros here I was wondering what the most efficent technique would be to use?

Someone had an idea, but deleted it before I could finish reading it, it utilised this as it's first step:

Let
\begin{align}
R_1 &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc} 
a  & b & 0   \\
2d & e & 2b  \\
0  & d & g   
\end{array}
\right)
%%%%
\quad
%%%%
R_2 = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc} 
 c  & 0 & 0  \\
 0  & f & 0  \\
 0  & 0 & h  
\end{array}
\right)\\
%%%
V_1 &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc} 
A  & 0 & 0  \\
0  & C & 0  \\
0  & 0 & F  
\end{array}
\right)
%%%%
\quad
%%%%
V_2 = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc} 
 B  & b & 0  \\
 2D & E & 2b \\
 0  & D & G  
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}

Therefore

\begin{align}
M = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
R_1 & R_2 \\
V_1 & V_2 
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}

EDIT: Can we extend the reduced row echelon concept to this?

Leaving us with
\begin{align}
M^{-1}=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
R_1^{-1}(I+R_2JV_1R_1) & -R_1^{-1}R_2 \\
-JV_1R_1 & J 
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}

Where
$$J = R_2(V_2-V_1R_1^{-1}R_2)^{-1}$$

Comment: I think for spare matrices the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) might be of help.

Comment: For your edit, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion

Comment: Ah ha!! There we go. Should be easy now.